# SharePoint HTTP requests monitoring and throttling: is it possible to adjust thresholds?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, resource-throttling

There is HTTP Request Monitoring and Throttling feature in SharePoint (2010/13/16) which we can switch on and off on a web app level. Is it possible to adjust threshold values for this throttling so that instead of switching it off completely we can raise number of maximum connections allowed? Or maybe there is an option to exclude certain accounts from this throttling (like local administrators on WFEs are excluded from lists thresholds for example)?

Answer (score 3):

You can configure it via powershell but before increasing the number make sure your farm will support it. here is the powershell

```
$uri=new-object System.Uri("http://www.contoso.com") 
$webApp=[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication]::Lookup($uri) 
$httpThrottleSettings=$webApp.HttpThrottleSettings 
$cpu=$httpThrottleSettings.PerformanceMonitors[0] 
$cpu.MaxValue=75 
$httpThrottleSettings.Update()
```

Read more here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2010/04/22/http-request-monitoring-and-throttling/

and http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-sharepoint-health-score-and-throttling-deep-dive

Comment: Thanks for reply - though it is is not very trivial how to make adjustments into max number of requests/requests queue... I have an app which is being throttled by this feature with 429 Too many requests and I assume what I need to increase is request queue threshold/counter?

Comment: also not clear how to make the threshold change per-user instead of server-wide. because you are unlikely to want to change this for everyone. you just want to give some app the ability to make more requests than the average joe, which you would do by allowing the service account a higher threshold than any other user

Comment: Nope, thats not possible. it is web application level settings.

Comment: Im getting error "The property "MaxValue" cannot found on this object" - @WaqasSarwarMVP.