# Is it possible to set up Sharepoint HTTP request per-user throttling?

Tags: csom, resource-throttling

In sharepoint 2010/2013/2016... I am working to understand HTTP request throttling.

I am doing file downloads from sharepoint using this program: https://github.com/nddipiazza/Sharepoint-Exporter

This program fetches lists, list items, and downloads files and attachments within those lists.

First you give it a sharepoint user, then it allows you to set thread counts of how many downloads are being done in parallel.

I noticed that regardless of the number of threads I choose, the download speed seems to hit a certain rate and won't increase passed that. Making me believe that there is some sort of hard throttle preventing me from hitting the server too hard.

See: [SharePoint HTTP requests monitoring and throttling: is it possible to adjust thresholds?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218382/sharepoint-http-requests-monitoring-and-throttling-is-it-possible-to-adjust-thr?rq=1)

The answer here indicates that there is throttling being done at the server level.

But I cannot touch throttling per-server. That is too general of a change and would affect other users.

Is there a way to set the throttling that is done **per-user**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, throttle settings are set at the Web Application level. It's not possible to be more fine-grained than that.